# Python can't find the module in Ubuntu_Linux

Tags: python, ubuntu

I used ubuntu Linux. I want to used python to draw fuigures by using modules from buildingspy. So firstly I set the environment variable for buildingspy by editing /etc/environment successfully. However, when I running the python, it told me no module can be found. the code is as below

```
from buildingspy.io.outputfile import reader
```

error : no module named buildingspy.io.outputfile.
P.S. strangely i can't set the environment variables by using 'sudo export' in shell
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: sudo executes things in a subprocess, so any changes to the environment would be lost when it returns anyway, but `export` is a shell command and not an executable to begin with so `sudo`ing it makes no sense.  How/where did you install the `buildingspy` package, and does `import sys;print sys.path` show?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have any Python package for `buildingspy` that I am aware of. I'm not sure what environment variables you're referring to, but it's pretty unusual for a Python module to care about environment variables, so you might want to add more information about that to your question. The primary problem here appears to be that you don't have `buildingspy` installed. What have you done to try to install it?

Comment: I just put it in /Downloads. Then I set the path to the environment variable. sys.path didn,t show. What should I do?

Comment: I downloaded and put it in Downloads folder. Then I set the environment path to it.